# PHP File Upload doesn't upload

Tags: php, file-upload, directory

Hi I'm trying to upload an image but it seems not working. And I think I have my syntax right. Can you help me out? Thanks

```
     $image_path    = "/uploads/" . strtolower($_FILES["profpic"]["name"]);
     //$image_path is just that I'm getting the file name so that I can get the path and save to the database

     $target_path   = 'uploads/' . basename( $_FILES['profpic']['name']); 
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profpic']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
```

Here's where it should go:

C:\xampp\htdocs\noel\uploads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this absolute path in `$target_path`

```
$target_path   = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/noel/uploads/' . basename( $_FILES['profpic']['name']);
```